# How to auto-play embedded analysis in a web

Tags: iframe, embedding, spotfire

I want to show a web with an embedded Spotfire dashboard inside an iframe, and it must be active all day and refreshing from time to time.

The problem is: Every time the web refresh, the iframe only shows a circle button. When the user clicks, then the dashboard appears. But I want to show the dashboard automatically, without pushing the button.

Is this possible? I didn't found any parameter/option like 'autoplay=true'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use configuration blocks, schedule updates or automation services? Are you using any of these? If so, there is an alternative to automatically press 'the button' with javascript on repetitive intervals as shown on [Spotfire Developer](http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2016/01/animating-visualizations.html) Website